# How to create unique delayed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have a method like this one

```
  def abc
     // some stuff here
  end
  handle_asynchronously :abc, queue: :xyz
```

I want to create a delayed job for this only if there isn't one already in the queue.

I really feel like this should have an easy solution

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473471/sidekiq-ensure-all-jobs-on-the-queue-are-unique/21481379#21481379

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but it hasn't been replied. 
Delayed jobs does not provide a way to identify jobs. https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/192

My suggestion is that your job could check if it still has to run when it is executing, for example, comparing to a database value, etc. Inserting jobs in the table should be quick and you might lose that if you start checking for a certain job in the queue.

If you still want to look for duplicates when enqueuing, this might help you. 
https://gist.github.com/landovsky/8c505ecab41eb38fa1c2cd23058a6ae3