# Avoiding simultaneous after_commit methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Occasionally, two database updates happen simultaneously, so that my after_commit method runs twice, creating two identical sidekiq jobs. How can I avoid this?

`after_commit :process_update_file, on: :update`

Comment: why do you need to avoid it?

Comment: Because it runs the task to process my file twice, and this particular task makes an external API call that's to a paid service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473471/sidekiq-ensure-all-jobs-on-the-queue-are-unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like the [sidekiq-unique-jobs](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs) plugin to run only one instance of a job at once. This is not appropriate for the "we never ever want to have this happen twice or a patient will get 2x radiation dosage," but should be fine for "we'd rather not run this twice to avoid paying extra under certain circumstances."

If you want to be absolutely certain that it doesn't run twice (good luck!) you can try something like [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) to ensure that you only execute a certain path once.